# Cant find the term firewire in a man page - ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, man

I went into a man page by typing man man and then typing /firewire but I keep getting a message that says 'pattern not found'. I have tried every possible solution

If the way I'm doing things is wrong, by searching within a man page, please could you point me to the correct way.

Comment: Why do expect to find the string "firewire" in the man man page? Are you trying to find _some_ man page relating to FireWire? Maybe you're looking for `apropos`.

Comment: iim trying to find the some man page relating to firewire

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for `1394` in the man.

Comment: Nope :-( still get the same message

Comment: I found both firewire and 1394 at http://manpages.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

For general information try [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewire) on Firewire (also known by its standard name IEEE 1394), or your favourite search engine.

`man man` displays manual page for the `man` program itself, and the `/firewire` causes the pager (the program that displays the manual page) to search for the word in the manual - which it doesn't contain. When you want manual on something else, call it with appropriate topic, e.g. `man sh` to get manual for the shell (system command line interface). You can also try using the `apropos` utility to search headings of man pages for a specific term.

Comment: I've tried many different varieties, man -k firewire, man firewire, but having no luck at all to bring up the term firewire within a man page.

Comment: Very likely because you don't have the manpage of that name installed. If you check the [ubuntu manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man4/firewire.4.html) you may notice, that it is provided by the freebsd-manpages package. If you install it, you should be able to read it off-line with `man`, but note that since it comes from FreeBSD not all information therein may be correct for Linux. For general terms like Firewire, USB, SATA, wikipedia (or a search engine) really is a better source to start with (if you want to get some insight).